# PySpark dataframe How to filter data?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with department, item id and count of those ids. There are 127 departments and I want to get the top 10 items for each department and list them. That means based on the item count, I want to list the top 10 items for each each department separately.  I have been trying to do this using groupBy and agg.max but was not able to. Example of the dataframe is listed below.

| Department | Item id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 101 | 10 |
| B | 102 | 5 |
| A | 104 | 12 |
| C | 101 | 5 |
| D | 104 | 14 |
| C | 108 | 10 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That means based on the item count, I want to list the top 10 items for each each department separately.

Comment: Can you please restructure the question and add what do you expect as well , also the important thing is where you have tried this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is based on the `row_number()` windows function.

- In this demo I returned the top 3 records per department. Feel free
  to change it to 10.
- `qualify` is new to Spark SQL. If your Spark version doesn't support it, then wrapping query is needed and the filter will done using WHERE clause on the outer query.
- I added the `Item id` to the ORDER BY in order to break `count` ties in a deterministic way.

**Data Sample Creation**

```
df = spark.sql('''select char(ascii('A') + d.i) as Department, 100 + i.i as `Item id`, int(rand()*100) as count from range(3) as d(i), range(7) as i(i) order by 1,3 desc''')

df.show(999)

+----------+-------+-----+
|Department|Item id|count|
+----------+-------+-----+
|         A|    103|   89|
|         A|    106|   68|
|         A|    104|   54|
|         A|    100|   52|
|         A|    105|   50|
|         A|    102|   40|
|         A|    101|   30|
|         B|    104|   94|
|         B|    101|   87|
|         B|    106|   74|
|         B|    105|   66|
|         B|    102|   48|
|         B|    100|   32|
|         B|    103|   14|
|         C|    105|   95|
|         C|    103|   94|
|         C|    102|   90|
|         C|    104|   82|
|         C|    100|    9|
|         C|    101|    6|
|         C|    106|    3|
+----------+-------+-----+
```

**Spark SQL Solution**

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('t')

sql_query = '''
select  *
from    t
qualify row_number() over (partition by Department order by count desc, `Item id`) <= 3
'''

spark.sql(sql_query).show(999)
  
+----------+-------+-----+
|Department|Item id|count|
+----------+-------+-----+
|         A|    103|   89|
|         A|    106|   68|
|         A|    104|   54|
|         B|    104|   94|
|         B|    101|   87|
|         B|    106|   74|
|         C|    105|   95|
|         C|    103|   94|
|         C|    102|   90|
+----------+-------+-----+
```

**pyspark Solution**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.window as W

(df.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(W.Window.partitionBy('Department').orderBy(df['count'].desc(),df['Item id'])))
 .where('rn <= 3')
 .drop('rn')
 .show(999)
)

+----------+-------+-----+
|Department|Item id|count|
+----------+-------+-----+
|         A|    103|   89|
|         A|    106|   68|
|         A|    104|   54|
|         B|    104|   94|
|         B|    101|   87|
|         B|    106|   74|
|         C|    105|   95|
|         C|    103|   94|
|         C|    102|   90|
+----------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Works well. And also do you know how to filter the dataframe and get separate departments into different dataframes. Say all the top As to a dataframe called A, and B and so on. Thank you again

Comment: You can open a new question for this. although I doubt the motivation behind this split